# How to set default audio device when two playback devices with same names are connected

Tags: windows, audio, playback, setdefault

I am trying to Set default audio device when two playback devices with same names are connected.

**Details:**
For single or playback devices with a different name, I can set default using nircmd.exe. But When connecting a USB Speaker in my laptop. In Playback devices it is showing two Speakers with the same name as "Speakers". In this scenario, I'm  not able to set default playback device as per my request. It is by default setting first Speaker as Set Default.

So can anybody please help me on this.

[image: Refer image for this Scenario]

Comment: Do you intend to write your own switcher program or is this a end-user question?

Comment: Yes I intend to write my own switcher program. Initially I started with automation of set default playback devices. I was able to handle the situation when only one playback device or two playback devices with different names are connected.  But for devices sharing same name I was not able to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Solution. For this we can just refer First Child of Speaker. If it matches with your requirement. Then we'll get the reference of that and perform suitable action.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to rename entries, through right-click "Properties".
No info if it persists through removals.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming entries does not persist.

However, in addition to nircmd, nirsoft also provides a tool named [SoundVolumeView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html) which can handle devices having the same name thanks to a "Command-line Friendly ID"

```
.\SoundVolumeView.exe /sjson list.json
```

returns a list of available devices in list.json

Example :

```
[
  {
    "Name":"5 - PL4071UH",
    "Type":"Device",
    "Device Name":"AMD High Definition Audio Device",
    "Command-Line Friendly ID":"AMD High Definition Audio Device\\Device\\5 - PL4071UH\\Render",
    ....
  },
  {
    "Name":"Casque",
    "Type":"Device",
    "Device Name":"Tronsmart Onyx Ace Hands-Free AG Audio",
    "Command-Line Friendly ID":"Tronsmart Onyx Ace Hands-Free AG Audio\\Device\\Casque\\Capture",
    ...
  }
]
```

And then, you can change device with :

```
.\SoundVolumeView.exe /SetDefault "AMD High Definition Audio Device\\Device\\5 - PL4071UH\\Render"
```